# Камушков или камушек?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Загадочная история всех этих камушков (или камушек)... Как правильно?

Comment: @Артём Луговой, здравствуйте. Хочу спросить, как Вы вносите изменения в вопросе или ответе всего лишь по одному-двум символам? Когда я собираюсь что-то исправить, мне пишут, что нужно изменить не менее шести. Может, это зависит от репутации и привилегий? Спасибо.

Comment: @Александр: здравствуйте, Александр! Да, когда кто-то набирает тысячу баллов, он может править, насколько хочет, хоть на один символ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: Загадочная история всех **этих камушков** (Р.п.).

В данном случае для слов ***камешек*** и ***камушек*** используется **окончание ОВ — основное окончание** для сущ м.р. в форме мн. числа.

**Из Нацкорпуса:**

Простенькое, **из камушков** разного цвета, различной формы, но, показалось Голубеву, оригинальное. [Сергей Залыгин. Экологический роман // «Новый мир», 1993]

Тут один **из камешков** превратился во Второго капитана. [Кир Булычев. Девочка с Земли (1971)]

**Камушек** — камушек, камушки, камушка, **камушков**, камушку, камушкам, камушек, камушки, камушком, камушками, камушке, камушках (Источник: «Полная акцентуированная парадигма по А. А. Зализняку»)